# Creating a process to retrieve data from a chart in a qlikview qvw in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, qlikview

I haven't had much luck finding any docs or examples on this. It might be that what I require is not currently possible but:

I'm trying to make a call to our qlikview server that retrieves data from a chart in a qvw inputting certain parameters. I am trying to do this in php. Can anyone point me to documentation or examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is get the data from a chart. This is not directly possible. But you have options:

- You can embed a QlikView object in a page. See this guide:
  http://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2013/06/14/making-qlikview-part-of-the-story-embedding-objects-into-web-pages
- Or you can after a reload, execute a macro, that outputs the
  contents of a chart, into a CSV file that you can place in
  webfolder. This CSV could then be read by PHP.